# Shell Script: Speed of transfer of a hop using command Ping

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ping, cut

Create a shell script that relates the speed of transfer of a HOP between the machine and the IP chosen. Use the PING command and express the result in kB/sec.

```
!/bin/bash
```

I create a temporary file

```
touch info.txt;
```

I take the second line of command PING stopped after two seconds
I post the results in the file.

```
ping -t 2 $1 | head -2 | tail -1 > info.txt;
```

I take bytes

```
cut -c -2 info.txt;
```

I take ms

```
cut -c 53-59 info.txt;
```

*Now, how to make transformations in KB and in Sec?*

Show result

```
echo "Result: .....";
```

I delete the file.

```
rm file.txt;
```

Comment: You should consider that `bytes/msec` is identical to `kB/sec`

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
bytes=$(cut -c -2 info.txt)
ms=$(cut -c 53-59 info.txt)
echo "KiB: "$(($bytes/1024))
echo "Sec: "$(($ms/1000))
speed=$((1000*$bytes*1000/1024/$ms))
speed=$(echo $speed|sed -r 's/^(.*)(.{3})$/\1.\2/')
echo "Speed: $speed KiB/s"
```

This is of course considering 1 KiB = 1024 bytes, where KiB is usually used for KB.

Answer (score 0):

RESULT=$(ping  -t 2 -c 2 $1 | grep 'time=' | head -1 | sed 's/([0-9][0-9]).*(time=)(.*)(ms)/\1:\3/g') 
echo "BYTES = ${RESULT%:*}"

echo "SPEED = ${RESULT#*:}"

For the conversion part you might need to use python or perl. In bash it is not possible to calculate fractional numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! WORK!

> touch info.txt;
>
> ping -t 2 $1 | head -2 | tail -1 > info.txt;
>
> bytes=$(cut -c -2 info.txt);
>
> ms=$(cut -c 53-59 info.txt);
>
> KB=$(echo "scale=5; $bytes /1024" | bc);
>
> Sec=$(echo "scale=5; $ms /1000" | bc);
>
> Speed=$(echo "scale=5; $KB/$Sec" | bc);
>
> echo "Speed of HOP: $Speed KB/sec.";
>
> rm info.txt;